# Laravel 7 : trying to get the name instead of id

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller, relationship

I'm trying to get the client name , address ect.. based on their relationship, but when I am trying to get the name for exaple i get the error Trying to get property of 'name' of a non-object.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Client;

class Evaluation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'evaluations';
    protected $fillable = [
        'expert',
    ];

    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
   public function index()
 
   {   
       $evaluations = Evaluation::with('client')->get();

       $users= auth()->user();
       
       return view('evaluation.index', ['evaluations' => $evaluations]);
   }
```

view

```
    @if (count($evaluations) < 1)
                                  <h1>Nici o evaluare nu a fost gasita.</h1>
                              @else
                                  @foreach ($evaluations as $evaluation)
                                       <tr>
                                          <td class="pl-1">{{$evaluation->id}}</td>
                                          <td class="pl-1">{{$evaluation->expert}}</td>
                                          <td class="pl-1">{{$evaluation->gram1}}</td>
                                          <td class="pl-1">{{$evaluation->client_id}}</td>    
                                          @php
                                               dd($evaluation->client_id->nume) 
                                          @endphp
                                         
                                          <td> <a href="{{ url('evaluation/print/'. $evaluation->id) }}">Printeaza</a></td>                                               
                                    </tr>
                                  @endforeach
                              
                              @endif
```

An I also have to mention that in my table is nume instead of name it's no english project.

Comment: Inside your blade comment or delete ```dd($evaluation->client_id->nume)``` and change to ```{{$evaluation->client->nume}}```

Comment: Do the `Client` table have a field `id` that correspond to the `Evaluation` table's `client_id`?

Comment: I think, you just need to mention the foreign key `return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, evaluation_id);` if `evaluation_id` in your foreign key, but may be you have different. So you need to mention

Comment: I have created in my create_evaluations_table one column " $table->integer('client_id);" because I have tried this way of " $table->bigInteger('client_id')->unsigned()->index;
  $table->foreign('client_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('clients')
                  ->onDelete('cascade'); but it's give me an error of "150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Comment: Encang Cutbray That's have nothing do to with it , i was only dump it out to se what it's returning back to me

Comment: sta  I am not sure what are you saying, But Have you try to tell me that i have to mention the client_id in my belongsTo relationship ? Cause My row name is client_id And it is located in Evaluations table , Imagine that the evaluation is a post and I have to save client id of that post not user , the client, I have saved the  client id, i checked it out and it's work but, client have more than Id, like address and name for example and i'm trying to get them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED, Relationship and all there was good, all I Needed to do was to create an input hidded for taking the id and add the Id on protected $fillable on client model not on evaluation model. It's work and in the view you have to call it like {{$evaluation->client->nume}}, "->client->" = is the relationship that you called. And I SOLVED even the Foreign key problem, in my create_evaluations_table the client_id column was bigInteger and in my create_clients_table the id of client that I wanted to associate was integer. All you need to do if you will have this error is to make them identically like if the id in the table that you want to associate is integer you need to save the integer there also.